# asp.net error Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, httpunhandledexception

I get the above error in my asp.net webforms application when using httpcontext to download a zip file. the code that handles the download works perfect when deployed to production server, but only on my machine that is where i get the error. any ideas what causes this ?Thanx.

Comment: Well you're probably doing something locally you don't do on your production server, like a response.write or something like this. once you used response.write or anything else sending a response to the user, you can't modify headers...

Comment: I dont change anything on producton server, this is the code i use: Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFilename);
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
Response.WriteFile(ZipFilePath);
Response.Flush();   this was working before, and now all of a sudden has stopped working. i use response.flush() because i have a method that needs to be called after the download (ie basically a method that clean a temporary folder) , if i use response.end(), the code doesnt crash, but then it doesn't download either

Comment: Have you tried to put the `AppendHeader` instruction after changing the content-type ? It looks like the error message points exactly to that... Note that the error could aswell be in the part of the code you don't show. And as a side note, you should put and format your code in your question, not in a comment...